# Unable to upload image to S3 via Beanstalk

Tags: spring-boot, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I couldn't upload image to S3 via Spring Boot application deployed on Amazon Elastic Beanstalk with the following method :

```
    @Autowired
    private AmazonS3Client amazonS3Client;

    amazonS3Client.setEndpoint(S3_REGION_ENDPOINT);
    amazonS3Client.putObject(new PutObjectRequest(S3_BUCKET_NAME, key, fileToUpload));
```

The log showed the following error:

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Permission denied
    at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
    at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:1012)
    at com.g2m.persistence.image.service.FileArchiveService.convertFromMultiPart(FileArchiveService.java:91)
    at com.g2m.persistence.image.service.FileArchiveService.saveFileToS3(FileArchiveService.java:44)
```

But when trying to upload image using local endpoint (running Spring Boot locally), I managed to successfully upload the image to S3 as well as retrieving it.

Any idea how this issue can be solved? It has something to do with S3 permission or nothing at all?

Comment: Did you reviewed your EC2 instance role? Are you using the same user/credentials in your local machine? There is a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41667916/upload-file-to-s3-on-ec2-instance-permission-denied

Comment: @siomes Yeah, I've reviewed the role and I used the same credentials as well when uploading from local machine

Comment: Please check if you have set the bucket policies and granted the IAM roles and permissions correct. Also make sure the paths you are giving for the files or images are correctly defined. :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you didn't instantiate the S3 Client properly. Could you check if you provided the proper credentials when instantiating?

Something like

```
AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey);
amazonS3Client = new AmazonS3Client(credentials);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers guys. @Tanmay Delhikar I actually use bean injection for accessKey and secretKey as follows :

**<aws-context:context-credentials>
     <aws-context:simple-credentials access-key="${accessKey:}" secret-key="${secretKey:}"/>
  </aws-context:context-credentials> 
  
  <aws-context:context-resource-loader/>**

So, it should be ok right? Even after changing to your suggestion, I still get the same error

Comment: Yes, that sounds correct. Does the bucket exist that you try to write into?

Comment: Yes, it does exist. It works when I upload image using local endpoint (Run Spring Boot locally). But uploading with app deployed on Beanstalk will return such error

Comment: @blacky246 I had the exact problem, had you solved it or did you figure out why the error occur?